# Live Component Updating a parent model from a collection child

Tags: symfony, symfony6, symfonyux

I'm implementing a LiveComponent that contains a collection of child components. Everything works mostly fine, but I don't see how can I [update a parent model](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-live-component/current/index.html#updating-a-parent-model-from-a-child) if the updated property is an array.

Is it possible to set the `dataModel` property to a value from the collection? Essentially I'm trying to achieve something that would be achieved by this pseudo-code: (notably the `'workShift.tasks.get({{ task.id }})'`)

```php
computed.tasks|map((task) => {
  component: component('WorkShift:TaskEntry', {
    key: task.id,
    task,
    shift: this.workShift,
    dataModel: 'workShift.tasks.get({{ task.id }})'
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via events in the components, see:
https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-live-component/current/index.html#communication-between-components-emitting-events

see also https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-live-component/current/index.html#actions-in-a-child-do-not-affect-the-parent

(Yes, this is a link answer only - I can't show any meaningful code because it's too dependent on the code kachnitel has and therefore won't make sense.)

Comment: Thanks, that is my current implementation indeed. I was trying to "clean it up" so that I'm not duplicating the re-render decision logic and triggers since it works for non-collection properties. But if it's not an option I may stick with it. Will see if there's any meaningful code to add an example